# What if the computer programs would know about the existence of each other?

Tags: memory, performance, virtual-memory, development

In modern computers, virtual memory provides a layer of abstraction, thanks to which the program thinks that's it works with the processor itself. I know it's impossible under the conditions of modern software development, but what if the programs would know about the existence of each other? That they're not the only ones, who work with the processor? Would it allow them to communicate easier and speed things up?

Comment: What about it? Programs have ways of communicating with each other and passing information between themselves, each other, and the operating system, within the parameters defined by the operating system, so this isn't really a "what if".

Comment: Virtual memory provides no abstraction. An app is unaware of whether it's in swap or in RAM. That is entirely handled outside its purview, by CPU & OS schedulers. Sandboxing may be what you mean… task separation… but that doesn't prevent co-operative tasks so long as they 'ask' the OS.

Comment: @Tetsujin By abstraction I meant the mapping of virtual memory addresses to the physical ones. Doesn't it together with the process of paging/segmentation takes time?

Comment: What does that have to do with any kind of inter-app 'awareness' or collaboration?

Comment: @Tetsujin An app must know, which segment of the address space is being used by another program to not overwrite it, I think.

Comment: @Kenticent *that* is handled by the virtual memory, programs don't need or want to know whether memory is "owned" by another process. Processes can easily find out what other applications there are using methods that are far safer than having everything operating in the same address space. The mapping of virtual to physical memory might have a *tiny* penalty, but it is handled in hardware (faster and more efficient than software) and has the benefit of being more secure as a result.

Comment: The app has no clue where it is in RAM or swap. It doesn't ever need to know. It's not the app's **job** to know that. It's the OS's problem.

Comment: You might want to look up the [Memory Management Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)

Comment: Thanks everybody for their comments, @Mokubai I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a name for processes that live in the same virtual address space and can access each other's data - *threads*.  Of course, threads don't have the security benefits of processes, but are used all the time where multiple sections of the same code need to run at the same time in the same space (or as concurrently as possible).

When multiple active executing streams of code can possibly modify data at a given time, care must be taken to make sure each doesn't accidentally overwrite data at the wrong time, and synchronization concepts/primitives such as critical sections, locks, mutexes, semaphores, etc. are used.

Interprocess communication (IPC) is also a thing.

One possible method is using the operating system's TCP/IP stack and implementing a client/server mechanism on a localhost IP address.

An independent service for IPC is also possible; e.g. D-Bus, a special broker or message routing service, or operating system facilities like the Win32 CSRSS (search for "Win32 message pump" to see how that works in detail).

There are also operating system facilities such as named pipes, local Unix sockets, FIFOs, etc.